# What does INTERNAL form properties mean?

Tags: theming, forms

On the Drupal [form-API page](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7.x), there is this paragraph that reads:

> Note that internal properties are not included in the table below, but
>   are included in the Properties list. These include: #built, #children,
>    #error, #id, #input, #printed, #validation_arguments

What does "internal" mean, as compared to other form element property types?

Answer (score 0):

**Internal** means that these properties are not supposed to be used by module developer.

Comment: Thanks. Is there some online documentation you can site about this?

Comment: Um... I forgot where it is. But these properties are generated from core code during building the form and many core behaviours highly depends on the value of these properties. If you change these values, it will breaks some functions.